# Upgrade to Firefox 9 crazy dependencies?

Tags: firefox

Today I logged into my Ubuntu 10.04 remote dekstop machine for the first time in a while. I noticed that Firefox 3.6 would be upgraded to Firefox 9. I typed "sudo aptitude safe-upgrade" at the terminal and found out that the upgrade would require 430 MB of disk space. There is a kernel update among, but I still think that 430 MB is very much. The list of dependencies required is very long:

```
apturl-kde{a} exiv2{a} firefox-locale-en{a} gdebi-core{a} gdebi-kde{a} hal{a}hal-info{a} icoutils{a} install-package{a} kdebase-runtime{a} kdebase-runtime-data{a}    kdelibs-bin{a} kdelibs5{a} kdelibs5-data{a} kdepimlibs-data{a} kdepimlibs5{a} kdesudo{a} kpackagekit{a} kubuntu-debug-installer{a} libakonadiprivate1{a} libattica0{a} libboost-program-options1.40.0{a} libclucene0ldbl{a} libdbusmenu-qt2{a} libexiv2-6{a} libgif4{a} 
libgpgme11{a} libilmbase6{a} libiodbc2{a} libopenexr6{a} libpackagekit-glib2-12{a} libpackagekit-qt-12{a} libphonon4{a} libplasma3{a} libpolkit-qt-1-0{a} libpth20{a} libqca2{a} libqt4-assistant{a} libqt4-dbus{a} libqt4-designer{a} libqt4-help{a} libqt4-qt3support{a} libqt4-script{a} libqt4-scripttools{a} libqt4-sql{a} libqt4-sql-sqlite{a} 
libqt4-svg{a} libqt4-test{a} libqt4-webkit{a} libqt4-xml{a} libqt4-xmlpatterns{a} libraptor1{a} librasqal2{a} librdf0{a} libsoprano4{a} libssh-4{a} libstreamanalyzer0{a} libstreams0{a} oxygen-icon-theme{a} packagekit{a} packagekit-backend-apt{a} phonon{a} phonon-backend-null{a} plasma-scriptengine-javascript{a} polkit-kde-1{a} python-kde4{a} python-packagekit{a} python-qt4{a} python-sip{a} shared-desktop-ontologies{a} smartdimmer{a} software-properties-kde{a} soprano-daemon{a} ttf-dejavu{a} ttf-dejavu-extra{a} update-manager-kde{a} virtuoso-nepomuk{a} x11-xserver-utils{a} xdg-utils{a} xul-ext-ubufox{a}
```

It seems crazy to me that so many KDE an QT packages are required to upgrade Firefox, if I wanted them I had choosed Kubuntu instead of Ubuntu. It also seems weird to me that hal and hal-info are going to be installed, I thought that almost every Linux disto was going away from hal because it is big mess, but now it is required?

Can anybody with an Ubuntu 10.04 installation confirm that they had the same massive amount of dependencies when they upgraded to Firefox 9, or is there been some sort of dependency mistake in my cas?

---

To include more information in my question, I tried to uninstall Firefox and then upgrade all the other packages, this was about 130 MB, then I tried to install Firefox again, but now only 31 MB was required.

The package installed without any problems and now my remote desktop has Firefox 9 without any KDE or QT dependencies. I think that pages load more smooth and quicker in Firefox 9, so this is great.

Comment: Can you see what the normal update manager does and add that information to your question?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrades on Kubuntu might have a lot of dependencies .Firefox needs only some of them of them

Such as the `xul-ext-ubufox`. But it is probably because you havent updated in a while.

Answer (score 0):

You may just have a lot of updates to do, since you said you hadn't logged in for a while. It's not necessarily all for Firefox.